# Opencv Extract largest region of interest

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have couple of images that look like the following:
The images are mostly on a  white background.

There are multiple pieces of clothing laid out on a white (mostly) background.
[image] [image]

I tried detecting the two pieces of clothing using opencv connected components.
Tried to take the largest two connected components,Unfortunately , i am failing.

I believe that this is possible but since i am a newbie to opencv ,could somebody throw some light on what can be done to detect the multiple pieces of clothing in the following images?

Any help is appreciated

Code that that i tried in python:

```
#Read the image and conver to grayscale
img = cv2.imread('t.jpg' , 0)
#Applt the median filter on the image 
#med = cv2.medianBlur(image,5)    # 5 is a fairly small kernel size
#Apply an edge detection filter 

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)

laplacian = laplacian.astype(np.uint8)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(laplacian,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
src = thresh1
src  = np.array(src, np.uint8)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(src,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
# You need to choose 4 or 8 for connectivity type
connectivity =8
# Perform the operation
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
# Get the results
# The first cell is the number of labels
num_labels = output[0]
# The second cell is the label matrix
labels = output[1]
# The third cell is the stat matrix
stats = output[2]
# The fourth cell is the centroid matrix
centroids = output[3]
src = cv2.cvtColor(src,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
for stat in stats:
    x , y ,w , h ,a = stat
    cv2.rectangle(src,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
    # write original image with added contours to disk
    #cv2.imwrite('contoured.jpg', image)
cv2.imshow("Image", src)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My output for the above code

[image]

**NB** : Its fine even if i can extract the largest object in the given image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty simple approach just using image thresholding and finding contours to extracting just the biggest item of clothing in the second pic. To get the other item you would just have to adjust the thresholding so that it is not wiped out, then you would search through the contours. Not the best solution, but it's a start.

```
img = cv2.imread('t.jpg' , 0) # import image as grayscale array

# threshold image
img_b = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (13, 13), 2)
ret, img_th = cv2.threshold(img_b, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# find contours
(_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(img_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(str(len(cnts))+' contours detected')

# find maximum area contour
area = np.array([cv2.contourArea(cnts[i]) for i in range(len(cnts))]) # 
list of all areas
maxa_ind = np.argmax(area) # index of maximum area contour

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(img_b)
plt.title('GaussianBlurr')
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.imshow(img_th)
plt.title('threshold')
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
xx = [cnts[maxa_ind][i][0][0] for i in range(len(cnts[maxa_ind]))]
yy = [cnts[maxa_ind][i][0][1] for i in range(len(cnts[maxa_ind]))]
ROI.append([min(xx),max(xx),min(yy),max(yy)])
plt.imshow(img)
plt.plot(xx,yy,'r',linewidth=3)
plt.title('largest contour')
```

This code produces the following image:

[image]