# How to get the slice index of a 3D image which shows the biggest image region?

Tags: python-3.x, 3d, medical-imaging

I have a series of 2D images that makes up a 3D image. Some image slices are fully black, and some contain the region of interest.

[image]

How can I get the slice number of the slice that contains the largest image region (for eg. here, slice 25)? The images are normalized (values are between 0 & 1).

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718211/opencv-extract-largest-region-of-interest) could be helpful. I'm not an expert in this but it seems like a good place to start by identifying the region of interest.

Comment: Do you have a label (e.g. binary mask) defining which part of the image you are interested in? Or is your region of interest the entire patient?